# Extracting emoticons from tweets

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Okay, I've been working on this for hours trying to figure out how to do this. I have about 47000 tweets from which I want to extract the emoticons such as :) :-) :( :@ :S :-[ :[ :-] :] etc.. but I did something horribly wrong. So, instead of storing these emoticons, I removed them. Anyway, the idea is that I want to clean up the tweets such that if they're like this:

askdfud:) sineirhlkj:D :)9iejsl. I want to put space between the emoticons and words. Also, I don't want to remove apostrophe from words like don't, doesn't. I'm doing this in R using gsub.

```
  jsonText <- gsub("http\\S+\\s*", " ", jsonText)

   #remove punctuation
   #jsonText <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[:][ ]|[:][a-zA-Z][(^DoO)]|[:][1-9]", " ", jsonText)
   #jsonText <- gsub("[:][^-(@$\\[]", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[!]", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[?]", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[,]", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[.]{1,2}", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[*]", " ", jsonText)
   #jsonText <- gsub("[#]", " ", jsonText)
   #jsonText <- gsub("[^#a-zA-z0-9]|[#]\\s", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[-]+\\s", " ", jsonText)   
   jsonText <- gsub("['0-9]{1,2}", " ", jsonText)
   #jsonText <- gsub("[a-zA-Z0-9][-]", " ", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("(?)[:]", " :", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("(?)[;]", " ;", jsonText)
   jsonText <- gsub("[:][^-)(@$]", " ", jsonText)

   jsonText <- gsub("[^a-zA-z0-9][']", " ", jsonText)
```

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with extracting the smileys http://regex101.com/r/eU0fV5/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Thanks for pointing it out. It was a duplicate, and I did get help from the other post. Thanks